# Get maximum int64 value using 2's complement arithmetic golang

Tags: go, math, integer, int64, complement

How to get maximum int64 value using 2's complement arithmetic in golang

I need to compare incoming int64 value with maximum value for int64 (not using math package). I don't want to use math.MaxInt64 value, I know that where are some method for int

Comment: you can try `1<<63 - 1`

Comment: You mean you need a function that takes a value, and return a boolean indicating that the input value is the maximum int64, taking advantage of your knowledge of 2s complement arithmetic? I won't do your homework for you, but here's a hint `return value + 1 < ???`.

Comment: You could just look at the value of `math.MaxInt64`, it's even duplicated in the documentation so you don't need to open the source file.

Comment: Recommended read: <https://go.dev/blog/constants>. It deals with a more interesting case and also explains how to work with bit shifts when dealing with constants.

Answer (score 0):

Found: const MaxInt64 := int64(^uint64(0) >> 1) or const MaxInt64 = 1<<63 - 1, also const MaxUint = ^uint64(0)